# Android C code, redirect stdout to logcat or string buffer

Tags: android, redirect, java-native-interface, stdout

Using OpenSSL libcrypto in Android. Some OpenSSL functions output content to FILE*, actually many C functions are doing this, for example:

```
int X509_REQ_print_fp(FILE *bp,X509_REQ *req);
```

in this case "bp" can be stdout. My question is how I can get the output redirect to Android logcat? Or in more common way, to a char array or string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing stdout/stderr with NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192749/capturing-stdout-stderr-with-ndk)

Comment: Sorry for my close vote; that particular question was a bad choice, and isn't an exact duplicate. There are other very similar questions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Include `android/log.h`  and define the macro as follows:

```
   #include <android/log.h>
   #define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "yourtag",__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I cannot make any change on the function X509_REQ_print_fp() but want to redirect its output to logcat instead of stdout or a file. I do know how to output a string to logcat.