# How to catch actual Android crash log?

Tags: android

I am experiencing crash on a project that has native C++ library but the actual cause of crash is not showing in the logs. The log only shows `SIGABRT` and thus I cannot determine if whether this crash is coming from the library or in the project that is consuming it.

```
I  START CARD READING INSERT_TAP
... other logs

--------- beginning of crash

A  FORTIFY_SOURCE: strlen: prevented read past end of buffer. Calling abort().
A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9116 (Thread-500)
```

I already added try catch in the code but still no stacktrace.

```
        Log.i(TAG, "START CARD READING ${mSelectedReader.name}")

        try {

           // Doing some stuff here.

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: Did you see: [SIGABRT in NDK-created background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30846735/295004), and [Capturing stdout/stderr with NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9192749/295004)

Comment: Check with `adb logcat` directly, some IDEs filter the log stream to only include logs tagged with your application. Also see if your crashes generated tombstones. You can use these to debug the application at the point of crashing.